# How to properly OCR typewriter fonts using tesseract and python

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using Tesseract-OCR version 3.05 dev in python to OCR some documents. The main issue I have is with number 4 in the typewriter font. It almost always misses it and outputs either empty instead of 4 or some incorrect text.
I have uploaded a sample image.[image]

I dont have to use tesseract as well, if you have suggestions on other (better) engines out there please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for digits only you could add a whitelist which contains only digits. Example in c++:

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI api;
api.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
```

If that doesn't work I suggest you train tesseract-ocr for this specific font. A good and clear guide can be found here: https://medium.com/apegroup-texts/training-tesseract-for-labels-receipts-and-such-690f452e8f79#.mpllnzu57

Hope this helps solving your problem. :)

Comment: I did set the variables, it didnt work, I finally figured how to train tesseract using your suggestions. Ended up writing an automatic module which trains tesseract given box files. Thank you